# Remove string Array that contain certain character

Tags: c#, arrays, contains

I have an array and a variable :

```
string[] StringArray = { "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $" };
string check = "$";
```

And I want to remove the "$" so the output will be :

```
foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Using `String.Replace` ?

Comment: You noticed that `stringArray` has only one element? It is not clear if your question targets on how to remove the charactere $ from a *string*, or how to extend this method to a whole *string array*?

Comment: In your current example you are initializing a `string[1]` is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to initialize an array with multiple `string`, then your initialization is wrong, if that is the case, this implementation should work:

```
        string[] StringArray = { "foo", "bar", "foo", "$", "bar", "$", "foo", "bar", "$" };
        string check = "$";

        var stringList = StringArray.ToList();

        stringList.RemoveAll(x => x == check);

        StringArray = stringList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using linq?

```
string[] StringArray = { "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $" };
string check = "$";

var noDollaBillsYall = StringArray.Select(x => x.Replace(check, string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate across the array with a for each, and use replace to replace the $ character with nothing.

```
for(int i = 0;i < StringArray.Length;i++) {
StringArray[i] = StringArray[i].Replace(“$”,””);
}
```

I can’t guarantee that this will work by itself, as I am not at my computer, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: That will generate an empty string in the index where "$" was

Comment: If there were a "$" in the string array, yes. But this is (probably) as desired.

Answer (score 1):

i would try using a foreach to loop around the array and a stringBuilder. inside the foreach write if(element == '$') continue. else append it to the  string builder.

if you wanna try this i'd write u the code lmk

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. I use .Replace to remove the desired character. This is my solution :

```
  string[] StringArray = { "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $" };

  foreach(var result in StringArray)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(result.Replace('$',' ').ToString());
  }
```

Maybe any of you find more efficient way, I'm really appreciate it  if you would to tell me

Answer (score 0):

Quite an intersting task; assuming that you want to process *each* item we can use *Linq*.
Another problem is it seems that we can't just replace / remove `$`: we should control
spaces as well, e.g.

**Given:**

```
   "$  foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $"
```

**Naive removing:** (e.g. `item => item.Replace("$", string.Empty)`)

```
   "  foo bar foo  bar $ foo bar " <- note spaces
```

**Actual requirement:**

```
   "foo bar foo bar foo bar"
```

We can cope with spaces with a help of *Regular Expressions*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] StringArray = { "$  foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $" };

string[] result = StringArray
  .Select(item => Regex.Replace(
     item,
    @"\s*\$\s*",
     m => m.Index == 0 || m.Index + m.Length == item.Length ? "" : " "))
  .ToArray();
```